# How I can shows only the filename when I save a file in neovim

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I would like to knows if it's posible config the :w command to change the output message. I am using noice.nvim but when the path it's very long like this:
[long_path_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K81Gw.png)
It,s uncomfortably.

I try different functions just like that:

```
function show_only_saved_message()
    local file_name = vim.fn.expand("%:t")
    vim.api.nvim_out_write("Saved: " .. file_name .. "\n")
end

vim.cmd([[augroup ShowOnlySavedMessage]])
vim.cmd([[autocmd!]])
vim.cmd([[autocmd BufWritePost * lua show_only_saved_message()]])
vim.cmd([[augroup END]])
```

but it does not overwrite the default message:
[custom_output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmYRZ.png)

Comment: Use `:silent w`.